# Allow a plugin to be fed parameters

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that allows me to extend the base Lib class with a plugin. The plugin has it's own context and the library context is fed in.

```
Lib = function (test,width) {
    this.libraryProp = test;
    this.width = width;
}

Lib.extend = function(name,plugin) {
    this.prototype[name] = function() {
    return new plugin(this);
 }   
}

//The plugin
var myObj = function(lib) {
    this.chart = chart;
    this.pluginProp = 'plug';
    console.log('this library prop = ' + this.chart.libraryProp);
}

//A plugin method
myObj.prototype.ggg = function() {
   console.log('plugin prop in plugin prototype ' + this.pluginProp);
   console.log(this.chart);
   console.log('______________________________________________');
}

//extend the base library
Lib.extend('myObj',myObj)


var p = new Lib('instance 1', 900);
var u = p.myObj();
u.ggg();


var m = new Lib('instance 2',800);
var k = m.myObj();
k.ggg();
```

working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pnwLv/2/

It all works but I'm currently not able to feed any plugins parameters like so:

```
var u = p.myObj('param1','param2');
```

How can I re-factor the extend method to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Lib.extend = function (name, plugin) {
  this.prototype[name] = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        obj = Object.create(plugin.prototype); // Create a new object from the plugin prototype

    args.unshift(this); // Add Lib instance as the first argument
    plugin.apply(obj, args); // Call the plugin constructor with the new object as the context
    return obj; // Return the newly created object
  }   
}
```

You can then retrieve those parameters in the plugin constructor:

```
var myObj = function(lib, param1, param2) {
  this.lib = lib;
  this.pluginProp = 'plug';
  console.log('this library prop = ' + this.lib.libraryProp);
}
```

Comment: That is essentially what I need. I'm just going to substitute the Object.create out for a polyfill as I need Ie8 support. Thanks!